# Eclipse MinGW: how to have multi main in one project

Tags: c++, c, mingw, eclipse-cdt, program-entry-point

When I run a Java Program on Eclipse, each time I run a file, Compiler will check does it has `main`, if it has, I can run. And if not, I cannot.

But when I run a C++ Program (CDT) on Eclipse using MinGW, at Compiler doesn't work like that. After I compile, don't matter I run from which file, Compiler will search whole project to find **ONE MAIN** So, if I has many main file, I will receive error.

Please tell me in Eclipse, how to treat C++ Compiler to have multi main file and work like on Java: it just find `main` on which file I run from.

@: I have multi main file just for debugging purpose. !!!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unlike java in a C/C++ you can only have *one* main:

> The main() function is special; normally every C and C++ program must
>   define it **exactly once**.

<sup>( [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_function_%28programming%29#C_and_C.2B.2B) )</sup>

**But:** As a workaround you can use preprocessor to decide which of your `main`'s you want to use.

**Example:**

```
#ifdef FIRST_MAIN
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    printf("first");

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
#elif SECOND_MAIN
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    printf("second");

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
#else
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    printf("default");

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
#endif
```

Now you can decide wich one you want to use by setting proper flag at compiletime. If none is set you'll use the *default* one (`#else` part).

*Alternative:* Exclude all your files containing a `main`-function from compilation and include only the one you need. However, this will only work if those files dont contain more than the `main`.